# Some Websites are not loading in Swift Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, web

Hey :) I am new to swift and I want to create a WebView App. If I set URL to https://www.apple.com it works perfect. But if I change the URl to https://www.berkearas.de it does not work anymore. The Website is still working and online, and I have a SSL Certificate too. What can I do? Thank you all :)

```
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.berkearas.de")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }}
```

Comment: Did you configure ATS? See `NSAppTransportSecurity` at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html.

Comment: No I didn't configure anything. How can I do this?

Comment: How can I give a real frame?

Comment: Okey, I found my problem: I've added ```<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>``` to Info.plist

Thanks :)

Comment: @BerkeAras you should accept iMHitesh Surani's answer by clicking the checkmark underneath the score.

Comment: same issue, my browser is not opening lot's of website, only certain ones

Answer (score 1):

Just add `NSAppTransportSecurity` key into your .plist file then everything working fine.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
 <dict>  
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
 </dict>
```

[image: Screenshot]